# Retrieve contacts from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I need to display all the list of contacts available in user's phone in UITableView.I can retrieve the contactName , PhoneNumber successfully.But when I add the data to NSMutableArray it adds some unusual characters.Could n;t understand wht the problem is

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  Names=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ABAddressBookRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(allPeople);
    CFIndex numberOfContacts  = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(allPeople);

    NSLog(@"numberOfContacts---%ld",numberOfContacts);


    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfContacts; i++){
        NSString* name = @"";
        NSString* phone = @"";
        NSString* email = @"";

        ABRecordRef aPerson = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allContacts, i);
        ABMultiValueRef fnameProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        ABMultiValueRef lnameProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

        ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);\
        ABMultiValueRef emailProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);

        NSArray *emailArray = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty);
        NSArray *phoneArray = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneProperty);


        if (fnameProperty != nil) {
            name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fnameProperty];
        }
        if (lnameProperty != nil) {
            name = [name stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", lnameProperty]];
        }

        if ([phoneArray count] > 0) {
            if ([phoneArray count] > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < [phoneArray count]; i++) {
                    phone = [phone stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", [phoneArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
                }
            }else {
                phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [phoneArray objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
        }

        if ([emailArray count] > 0) {
            if ([emailArray count] > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < [emailArray count]; i++) {
                    email = [email stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", [emailArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
                }
            }else {
                email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [emailArray objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"NAME : %@",name);
        NSLog(@"PHONE: %@",phone);
        NSLog(@"EMAIL: %@",email);
        NSLog(@"\n");

        NSMutableDictionary *d=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [d setObject:name forKey:@"Name"];
        [d setObject:phone forKey:@"Phone"];
        [d setObject:email forKey:@"Email"];


        [Names addObject:d];



    }
    NSLog(@"%@",Names);
```

This is the NSLog of Names :

```
{
    Email = "";
    Name = Hk;
    Phone = "(975)\U00a0050-1890";    //Actual Number (975)050-1890
},
    {
    Email = "";
    Name = Nik;
    Phone = "1\U00a0(234)\U00a0567-890";  //Actual Number :(932)324-1343
}
```

Why r unusual characters being added for Phone Number ...
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: That `phone = [phone stringByAppendingString:...` statement looks dodgy!

Comment: In fact all your uses of `NSString` are sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "No-break space" (see http://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/).

It seems that such symbols can emerge in your address book via some external sync.
But I have no difference visually.

If you put in number in iPhone address book it will be automatically formatted with real unremovable space between parentheses and digits. It is not the case in your situation. You have no spaces at all visually. So in code you have no-break spaces.

Comment: Ok.Can u tell me wht do I do to remove them?

Comment: phone = [phone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\U00a0" withString:@""];

Comment: I would rather clear phone numbers with regular expression like /\D// - remove all non-digits.

Comment: No when I replace with the string I get error "Incomplete universal chracter name" error.

Comment: Try @"\u00a0" with regular u or in case of fail apply regular expression replacement @"\D" -> @"". Use the same method with option NSRegularExpression.

Comment: I confirm that you need to write \u00a0 with small u to succeed